# How to Change URL of data-href dinamically for facebook comment API using only javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

**Just want to change the property data-href from the node of facebook comment.**

**Facebook's javascript code:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11&appId=YOURAPPID';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

**Facebook's node:**

```
<div class="fb-comments" id="facebookComment" data-href="" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code might works:

```
document.getElementById("facebookComment").setAttribute("data-href",window.location.href );
```